# Foreign Key Constraint error thrown when data exists in related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

We have two tables, tasks and roles, where tasks has a foreign key to roles.  In our app, we intermittently get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tasks_role_id". The conflict
>   occurred in database "redacted", table "dbo.roles", column 'id'.

As part of our error logging/splunk stuff, we get a serialized object of the data that we're trying to save.  When looking at the object, the role id that's trying to be saved exists in the dbo.roles table, so it doesn't make sense for this error to be thrown.

The error seems to come in batches, occurring for a couple of seconds and then going back to normal.  Also, it happens across several role id's, all of which exist in the role table.

Is there something else in EF6 that could be causing this error to get thrown?

---

Other things I've checked:

- Data types match between the tables and the code
- No cascade updates or deletes
- No triggers

---

Create script for the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tasks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tasks_role_id] FOREIGN KEY([role_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[roles] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tasks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tasks_role_id]
GO
```

EF Code:

```
 public int InsertTask(Task task)
{
    var newTask = new task();
    newTask.role_id = task.Role.Id;
    newTask.name = task.Name;

    _dbEntities.tasks.Add(newTask);
    _dbEntities.SaveChanges();  

    return newTask.id;
}
```

Comment: what does the constraint `FK_tasks_role_id` say?

Comment: @Hogan i have added the code for the constraint to the question

Comment: can you post a pice of code that show what you are doing to get this exception?

Comment: @YairI it has been added

Comment: Are you sure that the value in "task.Role.Id" is valid?

Comment: @Fleshy as far as i have been able to tell, yes.  there are multiple other, older records with that same role id, so for it to not have existed at that time the referential integrity to older data would have been broken.

Comment: Yes, but during debug, does the task.Role.Id variable hold a value that is in fact in the foreign table at the time of execution?

Comment: Also, does your model contain fk's to any other tables?

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs if you try to insert a task with a wrong (missing) roles.Id. Please check, if your database contains the selected roles.Id.

Comment: "When looking at the object, the role id that's trying to be saved exists in the dbo.roles table, so it doesn't make sense for this error to be thrown." - from my question

Comment: Sorry, I don't read this. In this case, it could be a problem with locked rows through a transaction (not readable data rows) and a deadlock (self healing system).

Comment: looking at SentryOne for the server during a time period that we experience this issue shows no blocking, no deadlocks, and no long running queries.